# Maven failsafe systemPropertyVariables

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, maven-failsafe-plugin

I defined some `systemPropertyVariables` for the `maven-failsafe-plugin`.
When the integration tests are run during the integration phase, the `systemPropertyVariables`are picked up correctly.

When I run a single test via my IDE (IntelliJ), the `systemPropertyVariables`are also picked up but I do not want that.

Is there a way to prevent this, without using maven profiles?

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*End2EndTest.java</include>
                    </includes>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <tomcat.host>host</tomcat.host>
                        <tomcat.port>8080</tomcat.port>
                        <tomcat.context>/</tomcat.context>
                        <tests.browser.name>chrome</tests.browser.name>
                        <tests.selenium.grid.address>http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/</tests.selenium.grid.address>
                        <spring.profiles.active>build</spring.profiles.active>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
     </build>
```

Thanks in advance.
Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `configuration` element is at the *plugin* level, thus it will apply for all builds. To limit it, create an execution and move the configuration into it.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
    <configuration>
        <!-- this configuration applies to all builds
             using this plugin, whether by specific
             goal, or phase.  -->
        <includes>
            <include>**/*End2EndTest.java</include>
        </includes>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <!-- this configuration only is used if
                 the integration-test phase, or later
                 phase, is executed -->
            <id>integration-test</id>
            <phase>integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>integration-test</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <tomcat.host>host</tomcat.host>
                    <tomcat.port>8080</tomcat.port>
                    <tomcat.context>/</tomcat.context>
                    <tests.browser.name>chrome</tests.browser.name>
                    <tests.selenium.grid.address>http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/</tests.selenium.grid.address>
                    <spring.profiles.active>build</spring.profiles.active>
                </systemPropertyVariables>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>    
</plugin>
```

With this in place:

- `mvn failsafe:integration-test` would NOT pick up the system properties.
- `mvn integration-test`, `mvn verify`, `mvn deploy` etc *will* use them.
- Any of the commands will use the `includes`.

Comment: Isn't this reversed? Shouldn't the answer say that the `failsafe:integration-test` WILL pick up the system properties while `mvn integration-test`, `mvn verify`, and `mvn deploy` will NOT use them?

Comment: @axiopisty, no, it is correct as written. The example execution is bound to Maven _phase_ `integration-test`, so it will only run if that phase (or a later one) is run. `mvn failsafe:integration-test` is running a _goal_, not a phase, thus the execution isn't used, and system properties are not applied.